# Windows Defender command prompt quarantine control - how to use MpCmdRun.exe to see the same thing the GUI sees?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-defender

When working with Windows Defender, it appears that a command prompt version of the utility is available to control certain functionality.  [See details on mpcmdrun.exe here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/command-line-arguments-windows-defender-antivirus).

One thing it indicates is that you can restore quarantined items through the following:

```
# First navigate to your proper Windows Defender folder in admin elevated cmd.exe, eg:
C:\Windows\system32> cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.2003.8-0

# To list quarantine:
MpCmdRun.exe -Restore -ListAll

# To restore quarantined items:
MpCmdRun.exe -Restore -All
```

However when I run either of these commands I get

```
No quarantined items
```

I can assure you that there are indeed items in quarantine presently and I can test this within the GUI such that I both see them and can restore them.

Any idea as to why the GUI version of Windows Defender appears to be disconnected from the cmd.exe tool such that they're not seeing the same internal data?